# How to set TextOptions for a TextBlock in code behind in c# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding dynamically generated textblock in code behind in WPF. I need to set the following properties for this textblock in code behind but I am not able to do so:

- TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
- RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode='NearestNeighbor"
- RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"

I cannot find them in code behind or any way to do so. 
Can anyone please suggest how these properties can be set in code ?

Comment: Use the static set methods, e.g. [RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.setbitmapscalingmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same solution ... here it is :)

In my case I set the properties for a RichTextBox

```
richTxtEditor.SetValue(TextOptions.TextRenderingModeProperty, TextRenderingMode.Aliased)
richTxtEditor.SetValue(TextOptions.TextRenderingModeProperty, TextRenderingMode.Auto)
richTxtEditor.SetValue(TextOptions.TextRenderingModeProperty, TextRenderingMode.ClearType)
richTxtEditor.SetValue(TextOptions.TextRenderingModeProperty, TextRenderingMode.Grayscale)

richTxtEditor.SetValue(TextOptions.TextFormattingModeProperty, TextFormattingMode.Display)
richTxtEditor.SetValue(TextOptions.TextFormattingModeProperty, TextFormattingMode.Ideal)

richTxtEditor.SetValue(TextOptions.TextHintingModeProperty, TextHintingMode.Animated)
richTxtEditor.SetValue(TextOptions.TextHintingModeProperty, TextHintingMode.Auto)
richTxtEditor.SetValue(TextOptions.TextHintingModeProperty, TextHintingMode.Fixed)
```